# git bash closes immediately

Tags: bash, git

I start git bash and it flashes open for a second and then closes.
Please how can I fix it?

**Background:**
My computer is a dell laptop using Windows 8 version 6.3 (build 9600). After forking a big repo and cloning half of it onto my computer, 
it was taking too long, so I closed git bash. Then I encountered the problem that it closes right away when I open it.

**Title that appears** in top of git bash window
/usr/bin/bash --login -i

**What have I already tried**, yet to no avail?

1. I rebooted the computer.
2. I uninstalled and reinstalled git bash.
3. I tried editing .bash-profile.
4. I tried running git bash from the git command and windows command prompt. Same problem occurred. But no error message appeared.
5. I tried deleting the big repo which I had partly cloned.

I expect git bash to stay open so I can use it.
What actually happens is that it closes immediately after opening it.

Comment: Try setting set ```GIT_TRACE=true``` in command prompt and then run ```git```. You may get some debug info. And what is the output of ```git --version --build-options```?

Comment: I tried typing git trac true as follows, but got the error below. 
C:\Users\yishai and shira\Git>GIT_TRACE=true
'GIT_TRACE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\yishai and shira\Git>

Comment: I typed into the command prompt git --version --build-options and I got the following result... 
C:\Users\yishai and shira\Git>git --version --build-options
git version 2.20.1.windows.1
cpu: x86_64
built from commit: 7c9fbc07db0e2939b36095df45864b8cda19b64f
sizeof-long: 4
sizeof-size_t: 8

Comment: Sorry, it is ```set GIT_TRACE=true```. Looks like "set" was left outside in my first comment. But it is good that basic git exe is working fine. Hope you will get some useful hint from TRACE. Please update your question with result screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I would launch Git Bash from a command prompt. It may be writing a message to stderr that you won't see if you launch it from the Start menu.

Open a command prompt and, assuming Git is installed in the default location, enter the command

"C:\Program Files"\Git\git-bash.exe

Comment: No, opening git bash from the command prompt results in the same error.

Comment: I want to show you a picture of the error as it comes up. Can I upload a jpg or png to this comment box?